# Creating a bounty on an unsatisfactorily answered question

Tags: discussion, bounties

[I posted a question about a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168469/why-does-post-without-parameters-not-return-json).  The only answer to the question was a "no repro" response that received four upvotes.  I can reproduce the issue reliably and don't find that answer helpful, and I'd like to put a bounty on it.  However, I don't want the existing answer to get the bounty if no one else responds (since it is unsatisfactory).

What is the proper SO way to do this, or should I just go ahead and take my chances with the bounty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Darin won't get the bounty if you let it expire. Only answers posted *after* you place the bounty are eligible for automatic awarding of bounties (in the event you don't choose one before it expires). An answer that:

1. has at least 2 upvotes and is the most upvoted answer
2. is the oldest in case of a tie per 1 above

will be awarded 50% of the bounty if you let it expire.